# why doesn't PATH work when I add the env in it and want to run a program under the env?

Tags: path, bashrc

I put a program `cow` under `/opt` and then I edited .bashrc by adding

```
export PATH=“$PATH:/opt”
```

so now $PATH has `/opt`

but when I want to run `cow` directly, I get

```
$ cow
The program 'cow' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install fl-cow
```

I still need to run `/opt/cow`

what is wrong?

Comment: (btw I hope you did not really use Unicode quotes `“$PATH:/opt”`) Did you source the modified .bashrc file? what does `echo $PATH` actually say?

Comment: Feel free to accept an answer if answered your question, btw. :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you are using the wrong type of quotations (““) vs (""):

```
echo $PATH
/home/anon/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
sudo bash -c 'echo \$0 this is a test' >/opt/test.sh;sudo chmod +x /opt/test.sh
anon@masterbox:~$ export PATH=“$PATH:/opt”
anon@masterbox:~$ test.sh
bash: test.sh: command not found
anon@masterbox:~$ . .bashrc
anon@masterbox:~$ export PATH="$PATH:/opt"
anon@masterbox:~$ test.sh
/opt/test.sh this is a test
anon@masterbox:~$
```

Edit: To further clarify the problem here, look what happens when I do it your way:

```
$ echo $PATH
# this is correct
/home/anon/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
$ export PATH=“$PATH:/opt” 
$ echo $PATH
# this is incorrect
“/home/anon/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt”
$
```

Bash does not properly interpret the PATH variable this way. Unicode quotes do not work this way on unix systems. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is, for me, 2 groups of files where you can define $PATH:
1. The bash files, like ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, and their /etc equivalents
2. /etc/enviroment and ~/.pam_environment
These places are some global to all users and some are user specific.
I recommend you to write the command you used in one of these locations, remembering that the files with the **~** only works with the user who uses the home directory where is placed the file.
Too remember, if you write the path in, for example, ~/.bashrc being for example the user Robertus, if you change to root the path will change to root one, following his own ~/.bashrc and company.

I hope you found my answer usefull

Answer (score 0):

Does cow work if you run it as:
    `/opt/cow` ?  If not, check the mode of the file 'cow'; it needs to have the executable bit set. If it hasn't, use: `chmod +x /opt/cow`

Comment: The shell is pretty clear that it cannot find the program in it's path. That is because when you :
$  export PATH=“$PATH:/opt” ;echo $PATH , you get:  
“/home/anon/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt”

 , so you can see that the shell is not going to properly interpret that PATH because the OP is using the wrong type of quotes and it not expanding properly. " is valid,  “ is not.

Comment: Although you are correct in that calling it directly will work, and the executable bit does need to be set.